# Save incoming frames from camera to video using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I'm trying to record frames that I read from an industrial camera (such as - https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/u3-3680xle.html) in my C# code as bitmaps.
I want to convert those bitmaps to video on the fly.

My solution until now was -> Sending those bitmaps to a virtual camera (e2e soft vcam) and then record the camera with ffmpeg - using this command:

```
-f dshow -i video=VCam -r 18 -vcodec libx264 Video.mp4
```

This is not working so well, because there are drop frames and the video is not smooth.

There is another way to use ffmpeg for converting those images to video on the flight?

Thank you!

Comment: A few ideas: (1) Pipe RGB data straight to ffmpeg `"-f rawvideo -i - -r 18 Video.mp4"` (2) If camera feeds its bitmap in BMP, use `pipe2image`: `-f image2pipe -i - -r 18 Video.mp4"` (3) Use [hardware encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro).

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas! 
This camera doesn't have a stream, this is the problem. 
I only get the images as bitmaps on the fly.